# FTP server return code: How to connect with a host using my own TCP server and Linux built-in client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ftp

In Linux there is a built-in ftp server/client. If you go to the terminal and type "ftp localhost" (Without quotations) there is an immediate connection to the local host with a FTP server return code 220. Then you are asked to input the host's name and password (331). I'm trying to implement my own FTP server to do the exact same thing. As soon as the client receives localhost and port, it must ask for host's name and password, but as soon as I write the password my program just hangs. This is my code to handle the user/password issue:

```
char login_user[BUFSIZ], login_password[BUFSIZ];
send(sock, "220\r\n", 5, 0); 
recv(sock, login_user, BUFSIZ);
send(sock, "331\r\n", 5, 0);
recv(sock, login_password, BUFSIZ, 0);
int x = strncmp(login_user, login_password, BUFSIZ);
if(x == 0)
{
    send(sock, "230\r\n", 5, 0);
}
```

For a connection to be successful both host name and password must be the same. Sending the FTP server code 230 should establish a connection like it does when using the FTP built-in server. However my program just stops and hangs until I press Ctrl+Z. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check the result of every system call for -1, and if you get it call `perror()` or print an error made up with `strerror()`, and then not proceed as though it hadn't happened. In the case of `recv()` you also need to check it for zero, which means the peer has disconnected so you must do the same, and not process; otherwise the result is a positive number indicating how many bytes were transferred. You can't just assume that value.

Comment: OT: "*In Linux there is a built-in ftp server/client.*" No, there isn't. However certain Linux distributions happen to have pre-install any FTP client and/or server tool(s).

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because the FTP client does not receive the `230` response.

The `recv` command does not magically wait for the "username" sent by the client. It's not aware of what a piece of data (or line) looks like in the protocol you are implementing. So it does not know it has to wait and stop on the "new line". You have to implement that on your own.

Depending on whether the connection is set as blocking or not, the code you have can either:

- not read anything from the socket at all, on either `recv` calls, never entering the `if` block.
- can read both username and password in the first `recv` call (the client likely sends both at once, possibly in a single TCP/IP packet).

You have to real read a lot about sockets before endeavoring in implementing something as complex as FTP server is.

Answer (score 0):

What you receive in `login_user` is not just the name, but the [FTP access control command](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/8_PortNumber.html) `USER …\r\n`, and what you receive in `login_password` is not just the password, but the FTP access control command `PASS …\r\n`; so the `strncmp(login_user, login_password, BUFSIZ)` will never return `0` (a fortiori since the strings are not '\0'-terminated) and the `230\r\n` will never be sent.